# Complex String Parsing

Tags: java, database, cjk, string-parsing

I am working with a Chinese database in text that saves entries in this format:

Traditional Simplified [pin1 yin1] /English equivalent 1/equivalent 2/

I've tried parsing it using delimiters (in Java).

This is what I have so far:

```
                    String delims = "[\\[\\]/]+";
                    String tokens[] = str.split(delims);
```

The problem is that the English equivalent also contains delimiter tokens.

For instance:

⿔ ⿔ [gui1] /variant of 龜|龟[gui1]/

How would someone parse this String?

I'm trying to get the following information from the String:

**Simplified**: ⿔

**Traditional**: ⿔

**Pinyin**: gui1

**English Equivalent**: variant of 龜|龟[gui1]

Comment: Please elaborate a bit more, the string makes no sense.

Comment: Do you mean to say you have a string 'a/b/c/' where b might also contain a the delimiter '/'?  Is it possible that a and c can also contain the delimiter?

Comment: Is it CEDICT? You may miss something. The format should be "Traditional Simplified [pin1 yin1] /English equivalent 1/equivalent 2/.../equivalent n/"

Comment: In the CEDICT - props to @wuliang to recognize it - the char `/` is used solely for separating definitions. There are as little as **zero** (1 entry so far) and as many as 16 (if memory serves).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using regex to cleanup the whole string.

```
String text = "⿔ ⿔ [gui1] /variant of 龜|龟[gui1]/";

String pattern =    "(\\S+)\\s*(\\S+)\\s*\\[(.+?)\\]\\s*/(.+?)/";

text = text.replaceAll(pattern, "$1;$2;$3;$4"));
```

`(\\S+)` ---> `⿔`
find continuous non-white space group

`\\s*` ---> 
find continuous white space

`\\[(.+?)\\]` ---> `gui1`
find everything inside **[** bla bla bla **]**.
**'?'** will match shortest possible answer.
e.g. **[** bla bla **]** rather than **[** bla bla] [ble ble **]**

`/(.+?)/` ---> `variant of 龜|龟[gui1]`
same as above, but find everything inside **/** bla bla **/**
**'?'** will match shortest

You can test the regex [here](http://www.regexplanet.com/simple/index.html)

---

Now `text` becomes:
`⿔;⿔;gui1;variant of 龜|龟[gui1]`

Next you can continue to use `;` as delims to split them

```
String tokens[] = text.split(";");
```

Comment: In the CEDICT - the dictionary the OP is using - there can be as many as 16 /definitions/ (at last count): /one/two/.../ So the regex needs to catch them all.

Answer (score 0):

The regex pattern is just a tad more complex, as there are often several definitions in the **CEDICT**:

```
矮小 矮小 [ai3 xiao3] /short and small/low and small/undersized/
```

So the regex would be:

```
^(\S+)\s+(\S+)\s+\[[^]]+\]\s+(/[^/\r]*){1,19}/$
```